ERROR: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'
I'm using youtube-search-python to get the URLs of an array with song names but this error keeps popping up:
post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

I'm new to Python and I've been looking around but I couldn't find nothing useful for fixing this error (at least that I understood).
This is the code that is throwing the error:
 elif "open.spotify.com" == url_procesed.hostname:

        try: 
            playlist = Playlist(client_id, client_secret)
            playlist_tracks = playlist.get_playlist_tracks(url)
            link_list = playlist.search_for_songs(playlist_tracks)
            print(link_list)

Here's the error stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Bot_v1.1.2\spoty_handler.py", line 69, in <module>
    playlist.search_for_songs(song_array)
  File "G:\Bot_v1.1.2\spoty_handler.py", line 48, in search_for_songs
    search = VideosSearch(song, limit=1)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\TarjetaCiudadana\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\youtubesearchpython\search.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.sync_create()
  File "C:\Users\TarjetaCiudadana\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\youtubesearchpython\core\search.py", line 29, in sync_create
    self._makeRequest()
  File "C:\Users\TarjetaCiudadana\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\youtubesearchpython\core\search.py", line 51, in _makeRequest
    request = self.syncPostRequest()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\TarjetaCiudadana\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\youtubesearchpython\core\requests.py", line 20, in syncPostRequest
    return httpx.post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'

The error must be in playlist.search_for_songs because it doesn't print anything. Here is the code for all of it:
import os

import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

from pytube import YouTube
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch

from dotenv import load_dotenv

class Playlist:
    
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret):

        
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret

        load_dotenv()
        
    def get_playlist_tracks(self, playlist_url):
        
        auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=self.client_id, client_secret=self.client_secret)
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
        
        results = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_url)
        artists_songs_dict = []

        
        for item in results['items']:

            track = item['track']
            song_name = track['name']

            #artist_names = [artist['name'] for artist in track['artists']]
            artists_songs_dict.append(song_name)     

        return artists_songs_dict 

    def search_for_songs(self, song_dict):
        link_list = []
        
        for songs in song_dict:
            
            for song in songs:
                
                search = VideosSearch(song, limit=1)
                results = search.result()
                link = results['result'][0]['link']
                link_list.append(link)
                
        return link_list
        
TOKEN_1 = os.getenv("MY_TOKEN_1")
TOKEN_2= os.getenv("MY_TOKEN_2")

playlist= Playlist(client_id, client_secret)
song_array= playlist.get_playlist_tracks("https://open.spotify.com/playlist/0drb98YI5Kk0ENtWXIS67y?si=bEHhpXlUThSyKkxNxkMCeg")
playlist.search_for_songs(song_array)


I believe you are using httpx version 0.28.0 or above. In this version, the post method really doesn't have the proxies parameter declared. Compare this:
>>> httpx.__version__
'0.27.2'
>>> 'proxies' in inspect.getargs(httpx.post.__code__).args
True

versus
>>> httpx.__version__
'0.28.1'
>>> 'proxies' in inspect.getargs(httpx.post.__code__).args
False

You might want to consider downgrading httpx to version 0.27 if possible, like so:
pip install --force-reinstall 'httpx<0.28'

I think a reasonable approach would be to try it in a fresh, separate environment first.

I have version 0.28.1
However when i try to install the older version using:
"pip install --force-reinstall 'httpx<0.28'"
It says it couldnt find the specified file, i also tried:
"pip install --force-reinstall 'httpx == 0.27.2'"
But still theres this error:
"ERROR: Invalid requirement: "'httpx-0.28.1==0.27.2'": Expected package name at the start of dependency specifier
'httpx-0.28.1==0.27.2'"

@JGEst02 Looks like you have packages installed that require httpx v0.28.x. As I mentioned, try working in a separate environment with only the packages needed for your task. If the problem continues, I’d suggest checking which packages rely on v0.28 and trying to downgrade them as well.

Got the version installed idk what was causing it i just uninstalled and installed the other version using "pip install httpx==0.27.2" Now it works fine thank you.

@Vitalizzare This solution solved a issue in yewtube. Thanks!
